# Проверка наличия строки в БД SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Добрый день. У меня есть поле для ввода и кнопка, которая добавляет строку в таблицу БД. Подскажите как реализовать логику. Хочу сделать булевый метод, который делает проверку "есть ли такая строка в БД или нет". Написал следующий код, но, мне кажется, что он не правильный

```
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String selection = "example";

        Cursor c = db.query("filtertable", null, selection, null, null, null,
                null);
       while(c.moveToNext()){
            String stringDb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("filtername"));

            if (stringDb.equals(selection))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }       
        c.close();
        dbHelper.close();
```

Comment: Ну да, true/false возвращается, а курсор и бд не закрываются

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

```
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String selection = "example";

        Cursor c = db.query("filtertable", null, selection, null, null, null,
                null);
        boolean result = c.getCount() > 0;
        c.close();
        dbHelper.close();
return result;
```

Почему нельзя просто `return c.getCount() > 0` , потому что в таком случае вы не сможете закрыть ваш курсор